# When is it best to use SpatRaster or RasterLayer?

Tags: r

According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75429709/15834162), if I understand it correctly, the difference between `SpatRaster` object and `Rasterlayer` it's a question of format and of the package used, but for my part I don't understand and I wonder in which case or context it's preferable to use a `SpatRaster` or a `RasterLayer`?

In my case, e.g. I use `rast()`When is it best to use  function to retrieve climatic data in raster form (from .tif format) as,

```
clim <- paste0(paste(directory, paste0("Bio",c(1:19)), sep="/"),".tif") %>%
  rast(.)

str(clim)
S4 class 'SpatRaster' [package "terra"]
```

but will my result be different if I use `stack()` function instead?

```
clim <- paste0(paste(directory, paste0("Bio",c(1:19)), sep="/"),".tif") %>%
  stack(.)

str(clim)
Formal class 'RasterStack' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
```

Why have two different functions? Are there cases where it's better to use `rast()` or `stack()`?

Comment: Package `raster` has `rgdal` in Suggests, but uses it intensively to read and write common `raster` formats. Indeed, a lot of functions in `rgdal` were added there specifically with usage by `raster` in mind. It is known that packages `rgdal`, `rgeos` and `maptools` will retire by the end of 2023, so I strongly suggest you to migrate to another alternatives like `terra` or `stars`. Source: https://r-spatial.org/r/2022/04/12/evolution.html#packages-depending-on-sp-and-raster